# Overleaf text input cursor offset on Arch Liunux

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, arch-linux

When I'm using overleaf (an online latex editor) the text cursor is displayed a few characters to the right of the actual cursor position, where text gets inserted by typing.

This is very annoying and makes working impossible.

This issue only affects overleaf and only my Arch Linux installation. It appears in google chrome and firefox. It does work normally when I use windows.

Any ideas on a fix?

Comment: I can confirm this issue on Manjaro Linux for Firefox and Brave.

Answer (score 1):

Overleaf uses the [Ace Editor](https://ace.c9.io/). The problem is reproducible in Ace, which only supports monospaced fonts. The solution is to force overleaf/Ace to use a monospaced font by either chaning the firefox default font or using this [add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-font-changer/) and select a mono font from the font list.

In my case the root cause was that my system fontconfig was overriding monospaced fonts to a non monospaced font, so check your /etc/fonts/local.conf:

```
 <match target="pattern">
    <test qual="any" name="family"><string>monospace</string></test>
    <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same"><string>Noto Sans Mono</string></edit>
</match>
```

Either remove such an entry or ensure that the matching font really exists. In order to do so, run:

```
fc-cache
fc-match mono
```